# C# keyboard monitoring - not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: c#, windows-10, keyboard-events

I've been trying to check if certain keyboard buttons are pressed simultaneously while my program is running.
This if the function I use:

```
static bool IsClicked(Keys modifier, Keys key)
      {
          /**
           * Return: True, if both modifier and key are pressed
           **/
          System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e = new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs(new System.Windows.Forms.Keys());
          bool isClicked = false;
          Thread clickThread = new Thread(
          keyToCheck =>
          {
              // WHERE I GET THE ERROR:
              isClicked = ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.LeftAlt) & KeyStates.Down) > 0) && ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.P) & KeyStates.Down) > 0);
          });
          clickThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          clickThread.Start();
          clickThread.Join();
          return isClicked;
      }
```

However, I keep getting a Win32Exception inside the "keyToCheck" function:
**"Not enough storage available to process this command"**

I went through answers to similar questions, however, the solution was changing registry values, which didn't work for me on Windows 10. It is also problematic when running the script on a different computer.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you give me some context as to where the function this is in is run? Also - pasted code is easier to follow than screenshots. I can't actually see the end of that line for example.

Comment: Changed :) @DannyStaple

Comment: @NineBerry changed it :)   Btw, you haven't written anything after "See also"

Comment: Why do you use a thread? Try not to use a thread.